# Como criar um vetor de tamanho variável?

Tags: c, array, memória

Em linguagem C é possível criar-se um vetor de qualquer tipo de forma que seu tamanho seja variável? Como fazer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Uma vez que você tenha declarado o vetor, não.

Contudo, você pode fazer o vetor ter tamanho diferente dependendo da entrada do usuário.

Por exemplo, se quisermos que o usuário entre com um valor para o tamanho do vetor, podemos fazer algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int *v;
    int i;
    printf("Entre com o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    v = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         v[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", v[i];)
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

O que nós fazemos é declarar um ponteiro para inteiros e falar que essa variável vai apontar para um bloco de memória com tamanho `n * tamanho de um inteiro`. Isso é justamente um vetor em C.

Depois disso, você pode usar uma função chamada `realloc` para ficar alterando o tamanho, mas não sei se era o que você pretendia.

Já em C++ existem vetores de tamanho dinâmico mesmo, os `vector`s.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas Virgili! Testei e funcionou! Muito obrigado! Porém, fiquei com mais uma dúvida, para que serve o o cast (int *) neste caso? Porque eu retirei esse cast para ver se funcionava e funcionou do mesmo jeito... neste programa, qual é a sua função?

Comment: voce pode aceitar a resposta entao :)

Comment: O cast pra `int *` é opcional porque em C ponteiros do tipo `void *`, como o retornado por malloc, são automáticamente convertidos para outros tipos (de forma similar às coerções automáticas entre os diversos tipos numéricos). Escrever o cast explicítamente ou deixar ele ocorrer automaticamente é uma questão de estilo. Fora isso em C++ essa coerção automática não existe e ai você precisa do cast mesmo (embora em C++ normalmente não se usa malloc)

Comment: Muito obrigado hugomg! Agora entendi! Não sabia dessa informação... muito obrigado Lucas Virgili e hugonmg!

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, para um exercício simples assim não tem por que inventar. Um simples vetor na pilha resolve.

Se o tamanho do vetor pode mudar de tamanho conforme os dados são entrados, então o `malloc()` sozinho não resolve. Eu [já respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177409/101) como fazer um algoritmo básico em que o vetor tem que crescer conforme a demanda, ainda que quase sempre nem é uma boa ideia fazê-lo. Então é possível sim mudar o tamanho do objeto a ser usado, ainda que na prática está criando outro objeto. Explico mais em [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101).

A única necessidade do `malloc()` em algo simples onde se pede o tamanho a ser alocado seria se o tamanho estourar a pilha.

Então ainda que a solução postada na resposta aceita esteja correta (não gosto do estilo de codificação adotado, acho que ensina algo ruim), e possa ser usada para um tamanho muito grande possível, vou postar uma solução mais simples para a maioria dos casos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int tam;
    printf("\ndigite tam: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    int vet[tam];
    printf("%d", vet[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LNb9jE). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/wovgogxnnm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/SimpleArray.c).

Você pode até colocar um `if` para impedir que tente criar um *array* com tamanho maior que a pulha, por exemplo 1MB.

[Pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101).

Answer (score -1):

Penso que seja isto que pretende, basicamente ao definir um tamanho na declaração primeiro que o vector, vai conseguir alterar esse tamanho da seguinte maneira.

```
 int main()
    {

    int tamanho=10, vec[tamanho], i=0;

    //Aqui alteramos o tamanho do vector ao mudar o valor da variável tamanho

    printf("Introduza o tamanho do vector: ");

    scanf("%d", &tamanho);

    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
        printf("Preencha o vector: ");
        scanf("%d", &vec[i]);
        }

    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++){

    printf("%d", vec[i]);
    printf("\n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    }
```

obs: Ainda estou em fase de aprendizagem, se detectarem algum erro avisem pf.