# Como receber um ponteiro de char via teclado em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Como faço para receber um ponteiro de `char` via teclado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente da mesma forma que outros tipos de dados. Eu sei que você já aprendeu em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34060/101) como usar o [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Há duas diferenças para ler um inteiro que você já sabe.

```
scanf("%s", texto);
```

O primeiro argumento indica que você está tentando ler uma *string*. O segundo é passar a variável que vai receber esses dados. Note que você não usa o operador `&` neste caso porque a variável já é um ponteiro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   char *texto; //declara a variável da forma como você sugeriu
   texto = malloc(31); //reserva o espaço em memória para 30 caracteres
   scanf("%s30", texto); //Lê caracteres pelo teclado e guarda os primeiros 30 em texto
   printf("%s", texto); //imprime o que foi entrado.
   free(texto); //libera a memória alocada
   return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CnLMQh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hxauoaob-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Read.c).

Você também pode usar a notação de *array* que Nem C na mais é que uma outra forma de trabalhar com ponteiros. Desta forma fica mais fácil fazer a alocação de memória. Este caso a alocação normalmente ocorrerá na [stack e não no heap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) como é feito com o `malloc()`. Para exemplos simples é mais fácil. Veja a resposta do Guilherme Bernal para um exemplo com *array*. usei o ponteiro porque foi o termo que você usou.

É possível alocar a memória para um objeto apontado por uma variável como feito acima no *stack* também, como é feito com *array*. Esta prática não é muito recomendada. O código abaixo é igual ao do `malloc` mas ao invés de alocar memória dinâmica (no *heap*), ele aloca memória considerada estática (que não precisa ser liberada depois, leia mais para entender isso no link que passei acima):

```
char * texto = alloca(31);
```

Nunca faça alocação de memória muito grande no *stack*. Não use esta área da memória para retornar o valor de uma função para outra, direta ou indiretamente. Se precisa fazer isto teria que copiar o dado no retorno já que o encerramento de uma função potencialmente faria os dados alocados no *stack* para aquela função sejam perdido.

Não vou entrar em detalhes já que parece que você está começando. Quando tiver dúvidas específicas sobre isto, pode abrir outra pergunta, se ainda não existir no site.

De qualquer forma é comum usar ponteiro para alocações dinâmicas no *heap* e usar *array* para alocação quando você sabe que é melhor usar o *stack*. Não tem porque inventar muito.

Comment: Muito obrigado bigown pela ajuda! Mais uma dúvida, qual é a forma mais usual e em termos de performance do programa é melhor utilizar, através do array mostrado pelo Guilherme Bernal ou através de ponteiro de char conforme ilustrado por vc?

Comment: @EduardoEncarnação ai vai depender bastante do tamanho da entrada e de o que você quer fazer com ela depois. Se é para um processamento imediato, é válido usar uma array local. Mas para guardar o valor e usar posteriormente, já é preferível alocar memória dinâmica como mostrado aqui. (bigown, esqueceu o free! (não que faça diferença nesse exemplo))

Comment: A forma do *array* é mais sintática, internamente tudo é ponteiro em C. Neste caso não vai fazer nenhum grande diferença (vou até complementar a respostas sobre isso). Normalmente escolhe-se um ou outro pela semãnticva que se quer dar. Você está trabalhando com algo que seja claramente um *array*? Vai com ele, senão vai de ponteiro. A coisa é um pouco mais complicada que isto, mas não dá p/ responder tudo em um comentário. É comum programadores inexperientes usar mais frequentemente o *array*, ele é ligeiramente mais fácil. @GuilhermeBernal o programa já vai terminar e liberar tudo :P

Comment: Hum entendi... agora ficou mais claro para mim... estou começando a aprender um pouco mais sobre ponteiros agora, então muitas dúvidas vão me surgindo.. estou realizando exercícios de strings no URI online judge para treinos de maratonas, daí me veio um exercício de string que me fez surgir essa dúvida... muito obrigado pelo explicação @bigown! Sua resposta ficou muito bem explicada! Muito obrigado! Grato, Eduardo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode ler uma string diretamente da entrada padrão do console usando o comando `scanf`. Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Digite uma frase: ");
    char frase[300];
    scanf("%s", frase);
    pritnf("Voce digitou '%s'", frase);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, no entanto que existe o risco de o usuário digitar mais de 299 caracteres. (mais o terminador nulo que toda a string tem, totalizando 300). Se ele o fizer haverá "estouro de buffer" e o seu programa vai provavelmente reveber um crash. Para evitar pode usar assim:

```
scanf("%299s", frase);
```

Qualquer quantidade de letras depois das primeiras 299 não será lida.

Comment: Agora entendi Guilherme Bernal! Muito obrigado pela resposta!