# Vetor de struct e ponteiro para char

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, struct, char

Por que essa sintaxe está errada:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {

  char* nome;
  char* numero;

}Agenda;

void adiciona(Agenda* reg, int i) {

    scanf("%s", reg[i]->nome);
    scanf("%s", reg[i]->numero);

}


void imprime(Agenda* reg, int i) {

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

    printf("Nome: %s | ", reg[j]->nome);
    printf("Numero: %s\n", reg[j]->numero);
  }

}



int main() {

  int sair = 0;
  int i = 0;

  Agenda registro[10];

  while(!sair) {

    int escolha;
    printf("O que voce deseja ? (1)Inserir (2)Imprimir (3)Sair\n");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);

    switch(escolha) {       
        case 1:
            adiciona(registro, i);
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            imprime(registro, i);
            break;
        case 3:
            sair = 1;
            break;
      } 


   }


}
```

E por que quando peço para imprimir o nome e o contato sai uns caracteres estranhos e caso seja mais de um sai repetido? Isto é, como se a primeira posição e a segunda do vetor tivessem o mesmo valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem dois problemas. Um deles é que [não está alocando memória para as *strings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136535/101) que serão apontadas na estrutura. Note que ali só terá um [ponteiro indicando onde está o texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101). E onde está? onde ele foi colocado? Em lugar algum qualquer. E depois [o acesso será feito em algum lugar praticamente aleatório da memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101) já que não se sabe onde foi alocado.

Alocando a memória com [`malloc()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101) garantirá que o texto tenha um lugar para ser armazenado e retorne um [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193507/101) para ele, esse ponteiro é que deve ser colocado na estrutura.

E não pode usar o ponteiro [`->`, o `.`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51204/101) é o correto já que a alocação das estruturas vão direto no *array* e não alocadas indiretamente, como ocorre como o texto.

Ainda teria o problema de não estar [liberando a memória com `free()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102162/101), mas em um exercício simples assim não é um problema.

Idealmente deveria ter um [limite de quantos caracteres podem ser digitados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37270/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *nome;
    char *numero;
} Agenda;

void adiciona(Agenda* reg, int i) {
    reg[i].nome = malloc(30);
    reg[i].numero = malloc(6);
    scanf("%s", reg[i].nome);
    scanf("%s", reg[i].numero);
}

void imprime(Agenda* reg, int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("Nome: %s | ", reg[j].nome);
        printf("Numero: %s\n", reg[j].numero);
    }
}

int main() {
    int sair = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Agenda registro[10];
    while (!sair) {
        int escolha;
        printf("O que voce deseja ? (1)Inserir (2)Imprimir (3)Sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &escolha);
        switch(escolha) {       
            case 1:
                adiciona(registro, i);
                i++;
                break;
            case 2:
                imprime(registro, i);
                break;
            case 3:
                sair = 1;
                break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/tIvxFy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vupqlxxa-maniero). [Também coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/MallocInStruct.c).

Comment: Obrigado bigown =D