# Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos

Tags: c, c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, stack, heap

O acesso de dados na *stack* é mais rápido que na *heap*? Por que alocar um objeto na *heap*?

Comment: Os conceitos de *stack* e *heap* não fazem parte da definição do C. Não é obrigatório que todas as implementações de C usem esse esquema de divisão de espaço de memória.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 17):

Sim, a [*stack* não só é mais rápida que o *heap* mas também é mais fácil manipular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). A alocação no *heap* se dá basicamente por estes motivos:

1. **Um objeto é muito grande para caber na *stack***.

A área reservada para a *stack* costuma ser fixa (é possível aumentar seu tamanho mas isso não está disponível em todas situações e é um processo complicado e tem desvantagens) e costuma ser bem pequena (em torno de 1MB na maioria dos casos de aplicações desktop Windows, pode ser menor em dispositivos com pouca memória, mas tem casos que pode ter até 4GB ou mais em alguns casos). Obviamente não podemos abusar do que colocar nele. Não só porque coisas grandes podem não caber, mas mesmo muitas alocações de tamanho não tão grande porém além do trivial podem acabar estourando o tamanho também.

Se ele fosse maior, desperdiçaria memória na maioria das vezes e não resolveria todos os problemas. Na maioria dos casos não deve-se alocar mais que alguns poucos *bytes* na *stack*. Alguns usam uma regra de no máximo o tamanho de 2 [palavras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101), ou uma quantidade fixa de *bytes*. Isto pode girar em torno de 64 *bytes* (tamanho típico do *cache line* do processador), mas é só uma consideração inicial para acender um alerta, não deve ser uma regra fixa.

2. **O tamanho do objeto é indeterminado ou é variável**.

Se você não sabe o tamanho do objeto de antemão, não pode contar que o objeto seja pequeno o suficiente. Mesmo que saiba o tamanho máximo e sabe que ele é pequeno, sem saber o tamanho exato fica complicado reservar o espaço na memória. A *stack* é uma memória contínua que precisa ser reservada. Embora seja possível alocar qualquer tamanho definido em tempo de execução isto tem implicações que dificultam seu uso. Usar um objeto sem saber o tamanho não é um grande problema, mais que torna o mecanismo bem mais complexo e menos performático. Você cria uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

3. **Um objeto precisa sobreviver ao fim do seu escopo**.

Este é um dos pontos importantes, provavelmente o mais importante. Quando falo em [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101), em geral não é qualquer escopo, mas principalmente o escopo da função ou bloco. Ou seja, se um objeto precisa ser acessado quando a função acaba só existe duas possibilidades:

a) aloca ele na *stack* e o copia para a função chamadora quando a função atual encerra;

b) aloca em outro local que não precisa ser liberado no fim da função.

Objetos pequenos serem copiados no fim da função não é um problema, de fato sempre haverá uma cópia quando passa algum retorno para a função chamadora, mas quando o objeto é grande a cópia será apenas da [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) para objeto no *heap*. Esta cópia é necessária porque os dados da função atual são desmontados no final da execução do escopo.

Como o próprio nome diz, a *stack* é uma pilha de dados que vão sendo empilhados quando entra em um novo escopo e desempilhados automaticamente no fim dele, é isto que dá a facilidade e velocidade desse mecanismo. Quando desempilha nada garante que o dado permaneça lá, ele pode ser sobrescrito logo em seguida por algum outro código executado na função chamadora que acabou de recuperar o controle de execução. Para garantir que ele estará lá ele deve ser copiado. Cópias de dados grandes custam caro, e nem precisa ser tão grande assim.

Para evitar a cópia cara, aloca-se o objeto em outro local que não funciona como uma pilha, que não tem a memória contínua, e acessa-o de forma [indireta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Não importa se o dado que quer se preservar é referenciado diretamente em um `return` ou dentro de uma outra estrutura de dados como uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) ou uma coleção que já foi passada por referência para a função. Este local é o *heap*.

4. **Uma liberação pode ser necessária fora de ordem da alocação**.

Por alguma razão você pode precisar controlar a ordem em que os objetos serão liberados. Isto não é possível na *stack* que sempre faz uma liberação LIFO (último a entrar, primeiro a sair) que é a base da pilha.

5. **É possível recuperar-se de um erro de alocação no *heap***.

Em geral quando se tenta alocar memória no *heap* e não consegue, é possível verificar e fazer algo para a aplicação não quebrar e quem sabe prosseguir sem sobressaltos. Se a alocação da *stack* falhar, muito provavelmente a aplicação quebrará sem maiores cerimônias. As linguagens não costumam ter mecanismos eficazes para tratar esse erro, até porque é complicado fazer resolver o problema direito, quando não é impossível, e é lento.

6. **APIs que o programador não tem controle sobre o funcionamento exigem o seu uso**.

Claro que poderia ser diferente e se houvesse a definição que nada poderia usar o *heap* este problema não aconteceria, mas isto não só é um problema real na forma como as coisas existem de fato e nada pode ser feito contra isto, mas também faz sentido ser assim. O *heap* não é uma memória contínua, ele pode ser loteado e fornecido pelo sistema operacional para a aplicação fazer uso flexível em suas várias partes. Então APIs díspares podem trabalhar juntas sem uma afetar a outra. Claro que quando elas precisam se comunicar, ou fazem através de área específica designada para isto e com contratos próprios bem definidos, ou acessam uma área comum com contratos também muito bem definidos, especialmente se podem acessar ao mesmo tempo. Isto se torna impraticável na *stack*.

Já escreveram uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163765/221800) com um código mostrando a diferença performance de um para o outro. É brutal mesmo. Não vou por o código para executar online porque ele precisa ser compilado com *flags* específicas para produzir um resultado relevante, mas na resposta podemos ver de 30 à 50 vezes de diferença. Mesmo assim, alocar no *heap* pode ser bom o suficiente para o que precisa.

Claro que tem otimizações que fazem isso ser melhor. Tem *garbage collectors* que permitem alocação no *heap* quase no mesmo tempo da *stack*, mas claro que há outras deficiências nele, não existe almoço grátis.

Ninguém conseguiu fazer o que precisa de forma mais eficiente em décadas que usamos computadores. Em computação tudo é *tradeoff*.

Poucas pessoas se lembram que existe uma alocação ainda mais rápida, que é a estática. Memória que já está alocada no início da execução é imbatível. Mas obviamente não tem muita flexibilidade. A alocação na *stack* é chamada automática e não estática como alguns acham.

Para saber mais sobre o funcionamento destes conceitos já tem uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) sobre o assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Cabe alertar que leak no stack é um caso alta complexidade para identificar. Inclusive tem ferramentas específicas para auxiliar nestes casos.