# O que torna um objeto elegível para ser alocado no stack?

Tags: java, memória, otimização, jvm, stack

Link do artigo: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPerformance/article.html#Escape%20Analysis

> "The programming language(Java) does not offer the possibility to let the programmer decide if an object should be generated in the stack.
>   But in certain cases it would be desirable to allocate an object on
>   the stack, as the memory allocation on the stack is cheaper than the
>   memory allocation in the heap..."

Segundo este artigo, em Java, um objeto pode ser alocado no stack e que a JVM cuida disto internamente. Minha dúvida são as seguintes: quais são os critérios que tornam um objeto elegível para ser alocado no stack e não no heap? É garantido que um objeto que possua os requisitos para ser alocado no stack de fato o seja?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Quais são os critérios que tornam um objeto elegível para ser alocado no stack e não no heap?

1. **Caber no espaço alocado.**
   Note que você pode definir o tamanho do *stack* com o parâmetro `-Xss`. Se você estiver trabalhando em um projeto crítico pode fazer uma "loucura" como passar `-Xss512m` ou `-Xss1g` para o comando `java`.
   Entretanto, como cada *thread* criada possui um *stack* próprio, você geralmente tem que balancear a memória disponível com a quantidade de *threads* da sua aplicação.
2. **[Objeto deve ser "local"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis).**
   Segundo a documentação podem haver 3 resultados da análise:

   - `GlobalEscape`: Object "vaza" do método e da *thread*. Por exemplo: ele é armazenado num atributo estático, armazenado num atributo de outro objeto que também "vaza" ou retornado do método.
   - `ArgEscape`: objeto é passado como argumento ou referenciado por um argumento na chamada a outro método. A JVM analisa o bytecode para determinar se isso ocorre.
   - `NoEscape` – Um objeto "local" ou "escalar", significando que a alocação pode ser removida do código gerado.

Após a análise, há várias otimizações que podem entrar em cena, tal como remover blocos de sincronização podem ser eliminados se a JVM detectar que o objeto não vaza para outras *threads*.

Entretanto, somente no último caso, se você tiver um objeto "local", a alocação pode ocorrer no *stack*.

> É garantido que um objeto que possua os requisitos para ser alocado no stack de fato o seja?

Não.

**Primeiro**, você sempre deve verificar o conjunto de *features* da JVM que você está usando. O que é frequentemente citado é que a técnica *Escaping Analysis* foi introduzida no Java SE 6 Update 23, então você pode assumir que as versões posteriores possuem essa técnica ([até a versão 8 a documentação cita isso](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis)).

**Segundo**, sempre verifique se existem flags para habilitar ou desabilitar tais *features*. Neste caso, parece que você pode fazer isso com `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis` ou `-XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis`. Verifique também se outras flags podem impactar nisso, tal como o `-Xss` que mencionei acima.

**Terceiro**, sempre faça o teste. Crie um mini-benchmark para determinar se a otimização realmente está ocorrendo, comparando uma execução com a feature [ligada e desligada](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/forax/2009/10/06/jdk7-do-escape-analysis-default#comment-965879).

## Considerações

Lembre-se de que o Java deixa o gerenciamento de memória escondido* numa caixa-preta por uma questão de projeto. Não é que ele não permite você explicitamente alocar um objeto no *stack* e sim que ele não deveria permitir. Claro que isso pode ser uma desvantagem se você for um *expert* em desempenho, mas isso também significa que o Java pode aplicar essa otimização para os outros 99,9% que nem sabem dessa possibilidade.

> * Na verdade o java permite algumas coisas que fazem acesso direto a memória ([`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)'s, por exemplo). Isso é usado, por exemplo, em operações críticas de I/O como em *drivers* de bancos de dados (e, claro, sempre acabam causando problemas de vazamento e estouro de memória).

Answer (score 7):

Primeiro entenda os [motivos para não poder alocar um objeto na *stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101). Aproveite e tente entender o [funcionamento da *stack* e do *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), se ainda tem dúvidas.

Então o normal do Java é só colocar os tipos primitivos na *stack* (eles podem estar no *heap* também), já que atende os critérios de não escapar o escopo do método, ser garantidamente bem pequeno, etc. (veja os critérios no *link* acima). Está previsto em versões futuras que o programador poderá criar seus próprios tipos com semântica de valor, como são os primitivos, assim como já [ocorre no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

O que a JVM pode fazer com as classes que, em tese, sempre são alocadas no *heap* é otimizar a alocação e colocar na pilha quando ele consegue determinar que isto é possível. Os motivos principais para atender isto são sujeitos à verificação da implementação real da JVM, mas podemos inferir algumas coisas que são os critérios gerais que regem a alocação de memória em qualquer tecnologia.

- A principal e fácil de descobrir é que **o objeto precisa ser pequeno**. Pode-se dizer que a JVM sempre sabe o tamanho do objeto quando vai instanciar. Só não posso garantir que é sempre viável verificar isto, acredito que sim, mas se por alguma razão houver um caso que não é, a indeterminação do tamanho impedirá a otimização. Em geral qualquer classe normal tem tamanho suficiente, *arrays* mesmo que usados em composição à uma classe é que podem ter dificuldade.
- O texto fala com clareza que é feito uma **análise de escape** para ter certeza que o objeto não sai dos domínios do método de alguma forma: por retorno direto, por anexar à um outro objeto qualquer que pode ser retornado, referenciado pelo argumento passado para o método, incluindo aí o parâmetro oculto `this` que dá acesso aos membros da instância.

Se não puder provar que o objeto não escapa, é preferível manter no *heap*. Mesmo que o objeto seja pequeno suficiente para fazer uma cópia, a semântica externa esperada não permite que se mude a referência pelo valor copiado.

Em alguns casos mesmo não escapando pode não compensar colocar na *stack* porque pode prejudicar a localidade de referência dos objetos que fazem a composição.

- É possível que existam outros critérios específicos que eu não saberia informar. Qualquer mínimo impedimento evitará a otimização. A JVM certamente preferirá um falso negativo que dificulta uma otimização possível do que um falso positivo que cria uma falha ou instabilidade à JVM.

## Não é garantido que o objeto vá para a *stack*

Como toda otimização, não conte com ela, só ocorrerá para ajudar. Se depender dela para alguma coisa está esperando mais do que deve. O que pode funcionar de um jeito em um momento pode não mais ocorrer em outro, seja por uma mudança da JVM, seja por mudança em seu código. Nem sempre um mudança deixa claro o que pode ocorrer.

A otimização depende de implementação, não faz parte da especificação que ela deverá ocorrer. Então depende do fornecedor da JVM, da versão que está usando e das configurações aplicadas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: vale lembrar que existem várias implementações de JVM, e esses critérios podem variar entre elas.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella sim, melhorei a resposta