# Por que os tipos de dados primitivos são fixos em tamanho?

Tags: tipagem, engenharia-de-software, independente-de-linguagem

Em algumas das linguagens de programação, normalmente C, C++ e Java, os tipos de dados inteiros são `int`, `short` e `long`.

O tipo de dados `int` geralmente são de 32 bits. O tipo de dados `short` é normalmente é menor que o tipo de dados `int` e o tipo de dados `long` é normalmente maior que o tipo de dados `int`.

O primeiro *bit* de um tipo de dado inteiro é o *bit* de sinal.
Um número negativo começa com `1` e um número não negativo começa com `0`.

Portanto, um tipo de dados de *32 bits normalmente* armazena números no intervalo `-(2^31)` a `(2^31 - 1)`.

- Por que não podemos ter um tipo de dados de tamanho ilimitado, para que possamos armazenar um intervalo ilimitado de números?

<sub>Tradução de [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607931) e [espanhol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questionss/547797)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem diversas premissas erradas na pergunta.

Os tipos inteiros tem tamanho fixos virtualmente em todas as linguagens de programação. Até tem tipos numéricos que o tamanho não é fixo, mas eles não costumam ser limitados a inteiros. É complicado fazer o tamanho não ser fixo, precisa de uma infraestrutura complexa para isso acontecer. É uma questão até física, em geral as coisas tem tamanho fixo, precisa de algum componente extra para deixar flexível, e isso significa que "custa mais caro".

[O bit que indica o sinal pode ser o primeiro ou último](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/101), em tese poderia ser outro embora na prática não existe. Veja [O que é big-endian e qual a diferença para little-endian?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/101). Existem tipos sem sinal em boa parte das linguagens, C e C++ por exemplo, além de C# e outras, mas não em Java, por exemplo.

Vou entender que o negativo começa com -1 e apenas quis evitar o sinal.

Depende da definição o termo [primitivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101) não cabe aí, vou mostrar um que algumas linguagens consideram primitivo e não possui tamanho fixo. Pela definição que indica tamanho fixo sempre, então tem a ver com a capacidade do processador que é fixa, depende do tamanho do registrador.

Um mesmo carro não pode ter 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, e principalmente 64 ou mais lugares, ou tem que usar o carro com maior tamanho ou tem que ter vários carros e você apenas não fica sabendo qual está usando. Guarde este exemplo.

Para ter um tamanho variável precisa ter um espaço dentro do maior tamanho possível, que em tese pode ser ilimitado, ou ficar criando objetos diferentes cada vez que mudar o tamanho.

Para alocar algo que não se sabe antecipadamente o tamanho precisa usar [memória organizada para ter qualquer tamanho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), que é uma [memória mais difícil de administrar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121595/101), então ocupará mais espaço, [gerará mais processamento para cuidar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101) e possivelmente terá dificuldade para manter a confiabilidade de uso.

As linguagens que permitem que o número seja de qualquer tamanho possuem um mecanismo que trata da maioria desses problemas internamente sem mostrar para você, então te cobra o preço para automatizar o processo todo sem que você saiba. Ou então tem um limite apesar de grande e aí o espaço ocupado é enorme mesmo que não use todo ele, ou seja, já reserva um `long` ou algo maior que isso, sem dar a opção de melhor eficiência para o programador, não é flexível de verdade.

`string` costuma ser variável. Talvez em todas linguagens seja possível definir o tamanho conforme a necessidade (algumas terão as duas opções), e tem toda essa dificuldade citada acima, a ineficiência deste tipo é absurdamente maior que um inteiro.

Linguagens que não precisam de eficiência colocam tudo no *heap* e tem algum mecanismo de cópia ou lista ligada para tornar o dado "ilimitado". Todas linguagens podem ter isso, mas as que prezam pela eficiência colocam como opcional ou deixam para o programador se virar. Java tem [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html). [C# também](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (veja a "simplicidade" no [código fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,035eb7acfa6585a0)).

As linguagens que querem economia possuem um tipo para cada necessidade, até 1 byte pode ser um preço caro a se pagar, então tem tipo inteiro com 1 byte, 2, 4, 8, 16 e sei até de 32 bytes. É comum que 16 e 32 bytes já tenham que fazer algum trabalho extra porque os processadores não costumam ser capazes de tratar isso de forma direta.

Pode ver mais sobre em tipos mais complexos:

- [Como aumentar dinamicamente o tamanho struct?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163730/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)

Answer (score -1):

É uma opção da linguagem. Em Python, o tipo primitivo `int` tem tamanho ilimitado.

C é praticamente um "assembler universal" então os tipos primitivos são a exposição direta dos tipos diretamente manipulados pelo processador. Tanto que os tipos `double` e `float` não são garantidamente IEEE 754; eles são o que o processador entende por "ponto flutuante".

Java garante que os tipos double e float são IEEE 754, por outro lado limita o tamanho dos tipos primitivos para viabilizar uma compilação JIT eficiente.

Answer (score -5):

Acredito serem fixos pelo princípio  de que um dado primitivo é a representação computacional de algum conceito usado no nosso cotidiano como por exemplo: os números, as letras do alfabeto e os sinais de pontuação que são as bases da programação.