# Ponteiro e alocação de memória

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

Sei que ponteiro armazena endereço de memória. E uma variável armazena um valor. Mas levando em consideração que tenho uma classe `class player {}` e crio uma variável `player p;` e uma instancia de ponteiro `player *np = null;` Qual a diferença entre essas 2 declarações. O que acontece no sistema, quais as vantagens de utilizar um ou outro.

Levando em consideração a mesma classe usada anteriormente, eu poderia dizer que criar um objeto do tipo `player` e criar também um ponteiro do mesmo tipo e armazenar o endereço desse objeto é a mesma coisa de criar um `new player()`? Ou seja:

```
player x;
player *z = &x;
```

é equivalente a:

```
player *z = new player
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sei que ponteiro armazena endereço de memória.

Um ponteiro é um endereço de memória.

> E uma variável armazena um valor.

Sim, inclusive esse valor pode ser um ponteiro.

> Mas levando em consideração que tenho uma classe `class player {}` e crio uma variável `player p;` e uma instancia de ponteiro `player *np = null;` Qual a diferença entre essas 2 declarações. O que acontece no sistema, quais as vantagens de utilizar um ou outro.

[A primeira fica na *stack* e a segunda fica no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Isso tem uma série de [implicações, vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101).

> Levando em consideração a mesma classe usada anteriormente, eu poderia dizer que criar um objeto do tipo `player` e criar também um ponteiro do mesmo tipo e armazenar o endereço desse objeto é a mesma coisa de criar um `new player()`?

Não exatamente, mas acho que entendo o que está dizendo, então podemos dizer que são quase equivalentes, mas a alocação de memória de cada um é em local diferente e tem um [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) diferente.

Comment: Seguindo a especificação de C++, faria mais sentido falar sobre duração de armazenamento automático e dinâmico. Coisas como stack e heap são detalhes de implementação, não é obrigatório que compiladores usem essas estratégias.

Comment: É verdade, porém praticamente ninguém usa uma implementação diferente disto. A resposta é adequada pra 99.99% dos casos, os outros só serão usados por pessoas muito experientes.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Maniero.