# Como armazenar uma string qualquer em C?

Tags: c, array, string, memória

Como faço para armazenar uma *string* (*input*) sem saber antes o tamanho dessa *string*, por exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (){
char nome[];     /* a array não tem tamanho determinado porque o input ainda
                  não foi dado */
printf("Qual o seu nome?\n");
scanf("%c", &nome[]);    /* não sei como colocar o input na array */
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No seu exemplo basta colocar 1 porque está mandando ler apenas 1 caractere através do `%c`. Então nem precisava do *array*. Mas tem solução se quiser *string*. Tem outros erros de sintaxe.

A técnica básica é criar um *buffer* (a variável `nome` no seu caso) para o maior nome possível que deseja aceitar e ainda colocar um restringir de quantos caracteres podem vir nesse *buffer* (usar `scanf()` puro é uma tremenda falha de segurança).

Tem uma [pergunta sobre o motivo porque é necessário criar um *buffer* com tamanho determinado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101).

Em geral isso não é problemático, a não ser que precise alocar um espaço muito grande mesmo, o que é altamente improvável para `scanf()`.

Se for muito importante alocar de uma vez o tamanho necessário talvez possa perguntar antes qual será o tamanho para alocar, aí basta usar a variável para criar o *array*:

```
int tamanho = 0;
scanf("%d", &tamanho);
char nome[tamanho];
```

Só tem um pequeno detalhe, como isto será alocado na pilha e ela não é tão grande assim, se esse tamanho for muito grande vai dar problema. Em exercício vai beleza. Em aplicação real nem é assim que se faz.

Na verdade a técnica mais usada nem é usar *array* no *stack*, e sim uma alocação dinâmica no *heap* através de [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Ainda assim é necessário saber o tamanho de antemão.

Se realmente for muito necessário ir alocando a memória conforme a necessidade para, teoricamente, economizar memória, a solução costuma fazer realocações. Muitos programadores criam uma função geral para gerenciar isso. O que é feito é ir lendo os caracteres e ir alocando em um *buffer*, quando ele encher cria outro *buffer* maior e copia o que estava no anterior e continua dali. Isso pode ser feito até mesmo aumentando de caractere por caractere. Obviamente a performance não é das melhores, mas para uma digitação em teclado é irrelevante. Há uma técnica de realocação ([`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)) que evita a cópia manual e em alguns casos até mesmo a cópia total do conteúdo.

Um código que faz isso seria assim (não considere pronto para uso em produção, eu nem faria assim de verdade, mas é o fácil para entender):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int size = 0;
    char *nome = malloc(2); //espaço extra para 1 caractere mais o terminador de string \0
    while (1) {
        if ((scanf("%c", &nome[size])) == 1) {
            nome[size + 1] = '\0'; //coloca o terminador
            if (nome[size] == '\n') {
                break;
            }
            nome = realloc(nome, ++size);
            if (nome == NULL) {
                printf("Ocorreu algum problema");
                break;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Ocorreu algum problema");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", nome);
    free(nome);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/h9bkee). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hdvqdctm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/EntryStringLengthUnknown.c).

Eu começaria com o tamanho de 64 bytes (*cache line* do processador típico, acho uma sacanagem objeto no *heap* com tamanho menor, ainda que faça sentido em alguns casos) e dobraria o tamanho em cada vez que a capacidade fosse atingida, assim a realocação teria complexidade logarítmica e ocorreria bem menos vezes. Inclusive porque o espaço ocupado no *heap* tem um *overhead* de *book keeping* de 4 à 16 bytes tipicamente, então não compensa ficar economizando poucos bytes. Fazendo assim terá desperdício de memória na maioria das vezes, mas acaba sendo melhor para a performance e em alguns casos muita realocação provoca fragmentação da memória que pode até desperdiçar mais memória ainda. O mínimo que eu usaria é 8 bytes porque geralmente não dá para alocar porções menores que isto (ou pegaria um número de acordo com o usado no contexto pela plataforma ou biblioteca).

Se fosse uma função pronta seria bom ter um parâmetro para o consumidor começar com o tamanho que achar melhor (mesmo dando chance para ele fazer escolha errada) e ter um tamanho máximo que permite alcançar, o que inclusive a última realocação (se a primeira já não for a última) usaria esse número.

Enfim, dá para otimizar muito mais este código.

Comment: [Nessa resposta do mesmo autor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231575/64969) tem uma sugestão de como melhorar a realocação aqui descrita, com complexidade de execução logarítmica

Answer (score 3):

Já agora, se estivermos a usar o gnu cc (gcc) -- habitual em Linux e disponível
para tudo o que é plataforma -- ou qualquer implementação compatível
com POSIX 2013,  podemos usar `"%ms"` para ler alocando o espaço necessário:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char *nome;
  scanf("%m[^\n]",&nome);   // lê linha, alocando o espaço necessário
  printf("bom dia, %s\n", nome);
  //   free(nome);
  return 0;
}
```

\thanks{@hugomg}

Comment: O manual do scanf recomenda usar `%m` em vez de `%a`.

Comment: @hugomg, obrigado (corrigi): estou sempre deactualizado! já agora será que isto funciona fora do gcc?

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo não sendo uma boa pratica ao meu ver nesta linguagem, aqui esta um link com a mesma duvida [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381867/declaring-arrays-in-c-language-without-initial-size), você pode fazer um alocamento dinamito na memória para que ela mude conforme o tamanho de sua string.

Lembrando que Char tem um tamanho máximo que pode ser inserido.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: De fato `char` tem tamanho máximo de 1 byte segundo especificação. Só alocar a memória dinamicamente não resolve o problema.