# Como deixar o tamanho da string ser definida pelo scanf()?

Tags: c, string, gerenciamento-de-memória, scanf

Minha dúvida é com relação a teoria.

Eu sei que é possível fazer uma *string* sem limitar o tamanho dela como:

```
char teste[] = "Teste";
```

porém, eu gostaria de saber se tem como fazer a mesma coisa, ou seja, não limitando o tamanho, porém sem falar o que quero dentro dela e sim deixando o `scanf()` limitar.

Comment: Veja: [Como criar um vetor de tamanho variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34060/como-criar-um-vetor-de-tamanho-vari%C3%A1vel?rq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade a pergunta parte da premissa errada. O código que cria a *string* está a limitando em 5 caracteres, não tem nada de ilimitado ali. Este código reservará 6 bytes no código para alocar os 5 caracteres mais o terminador, e no momento que a função for chamada será a alocado um ponteiro para essa região. Você não pode mudar esse tamanho.

O que pode ser feito é criar outra *string* completamente diferente, alocada na parte estática do código como essa do código, alocada no *heap* dinamicamente ou automaticamente da *stack*, e o endereço onde estará essa nova *string* pode ser colocado na variável `teste`.

[Em qualquer caso haverá um limite de tamanho. Não tem como ser diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101).

O [`scanf()` deixa você escrever quanto você quiser na memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168882/101), essa é até uma das críticas que se faz a ele. Só não quer dizer que a memória não será corrompida.

O que pode fazer é ler caractere por caractere e ir realocando a memória. Eu fiz uma [implementação ingênua em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177409/101). Uma melhoria ali seria ir dobrando de tamanho cada realocação e já começar com um tamanho razoável, isto tornaria a complexidade logarítmica. Ou seja, escreva seu próprio `scanf()`.

Leia [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).