# Mudar o tamanho do vetor no decorrer do programa?

Tags: c, array

Quero mudar o tamanho do vetor para resolver esse problema "A Lenda de Flavious Josephus":

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1030

Se eu tiver 5 pessoas com um salto de 2 vai ser da seguinte maneira:

12345 -> 2 e o 4 morreu e no próximo ciclo, o 1 e 5 morrem.
135 -> Eu quero mudar ou fazer outro vetor, com os sobreviventes.
3 -> E por fim o último.

Não consigo manipular o vetor dessa maneira, é muito complexo...

Comment: Isso é alocaçao de memoria dinamica, ao fazer isso nao pode definir `vetor[6]` tem de defnir como `*vetor`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um vetor de tamanho variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34060/como-criar-um-vetor-de-tamanho-vari%c3%a1vel)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```
int vetor2[4] = {1, 2, 4, 5};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ChangeSize.c).

Eu sei, você vai dizer que não mudou o tamanho e sim criou um novo, mas é isso que quer fazer desta forma, inclusive porque está usando um inicializador.

Depois de inicializado não pode mais usar esta sintaxe, ela só pode ser usada na declaração.

Tudo que está armazenado na pilha (veja no final) não pode ter seu tamanho mudado porque a pilha é uma sequência de dados contínuos.

Em tese até é possível reduzir o tamanho e deixar um buraco, mas também basta tratar o vetor como se ele tivesse menos elementos, afinal, principalmente em C apenas acessa-se uma área da memória, sequer está acessando de forma controlada o vetor em si.

Inclusive nada impede de escrever além da área reservada para o vetor, o que corromperia a memória, mas pode. Não quer dizer que está aumentando, mas pode escrever além, como se fosse maior. Claro, não faça isso, é um erro grave, mas o compilador deixa, ele não controla o tamanho na maior parte das vezes.

## O caso

Mas você quer fazer mais, quer eliminar elementos no meio. Então terá que percorrer todo o vetor e sempre que um for eliminado terá que copiar o próximo elemento para a posição atual, e vai fazendo isto até chegar no fim. No final terão elementos que não precisam mais ser copiados e nem devem mais ser acessados. Você precisará de duas variáveis, uma para controlar a posição onde está escrevendo no vetor, e outra para controlar onde está lendo. A de escrita ira incrementar em 1 em cada passo, a outra poderá incrementar mais vezes quando o elemento sendo lido não deve ser copiado. Faça um algoritmo e se tiver dúvida poste nova pergunta específica.

## *Heap*

Se deseja mesmo mudar o tamanho é mais correto armazenar no *heap*. Não que ele seja tão diferente e permite aumentar livremente o tamanho, ou que diminua sem problema algum, mas é possível fazer certo.

Se fizer alocação dinâmica você pode reduzir o tamanho, mas poderá deixar o espaço não usado sem uso, o que torna praticamente desnecessário fazê-lo. No *heap* você também acessa a memória livremente, então pode só acessar menos elementos. É mais um conceito do seu código do que algo controlado pela linguagem.

Se quiser aumentar de tamanho possivelmente terá que trocar o objeto de lugar para achar um lugar onde o novo tamanho caiba. E pode haver uma cópia de dados (em alguns casos pode haver otimização), ou pode manter lá se tiver espaço suficiente.

A alocação dinâmica ocorre com `malloc()`. E a mudança de tamanho da alocação ocorre com `realloc()`, e ele controla se precisa mudar de local ou não.

Um exemplo típico: [Como armazenar uma string qualquer em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177409/101). Note que é mais comum reservar um tamanho e mantê-lo assim em geral é mais simples e costuma sair mais barato na maioria dos casos. Não há lugar para preciosismo.

Uma resposta mais completa foi dada em [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101).

Um exemplo de código usando alocação dinâmica: [Como criar um vetor de tamanho variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34060/101).

Entenda [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Answer (score -2):

Se você não estiver limitado ao C, pode usar a biblioteca vector do C++.
Ele funciona de forma dinamica assim como lista, que é outra opção para solução desse problema.

Comment: Parece que isso se encaixa mais como um comentário na pergunta que como uma resposta propriamente dita.