# Como fazer com que o usuario escolha a quantidade de elementos em um ARRAY?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{

    int numeros[10];
 
    printf("Digite 10 numeros (separados por ENTER ou SPACE):\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf(" %d", &numeros[i]);
 
    printf("\nNa ordem inversa:\n");
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%d ", numeros[i]);
 
    printf("\n");
    rewind(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Neste caso acima o usuário apenas digita os elementos de 1 a 10, mas existe alguma forma de fazer com que o usuário escolha a quantidade de elementos? Por exemplo, primeiro o usuário diz que quer 12, 15, ou 20 elementos no array e depois ele numera quais são esses elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Se o tamanho do vetor não puder ser determinado na compilação ou pelo menos garantido que ele não será muito grande então deve-se utilizar `ponteiro` e alocar memória dinamicamente. Exemplo:

```
int tamanho; /* Variavel que guarda o tamanho do ponteiro/vetor */
int *vetor; /* Ponteiro que sera utilizado como vetor */

printf("Digite o tamanho do vetor: ");
scanf("%d", &tamanho);

vetor = malloc(sizeof *vetor * tamanho); /* Alocando memoria */

if (vetor == NULL) /* Verificando se a alocacao foi feita com sucesso */
{
    puts("Erro ao alocar memoria!");
    return 1; /* Ecerrando programa, pois sem o vetor nao eh possivel prosseguir */
}

/* Agora voce pode usar esse ponteiro como se fosse um vetor */

/* Seu codigo */

free(vetor); /* Quando o vetor nao for mais necessario entao deve-se
liberar a memoria alocada */

return 0;
```

**Algumas respostas complementares**

[Alocacao dinamica de memoria x vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120103/aloca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-din%c3%a2mica-de-mem%c3%b3ria-x-vetor)

[Como criar um vetor de tamanho variavel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34060/como-criar-um-vetor-de-tamanho-vari%c3%a1vel)

[Arrays sao ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91336/arrays-s%c3%a3o-ponteiros)

[O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variavel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106719/o-que-impede-um-array-de-ser-inicializado-com-um-tamanho-vari%c3%a1vel-em-c)

[char ou char malloc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141975/char-ou-char-malloc)